# Por que o tamanho do vetor está sendo alterado na função?

Tags: c

O Tanho vem como 2, quando passado a função tamVet()

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tamVet(int *vet){
  int tam;
  tam = sizeof(vet) / sizeof(vet[0]);
  return tam; 
}

int main(void){
  int vetor[10];
  int tam = tamVetor(vetor);
  printf("%i", tam);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque quando quando passa o vetor à função apenas fica com o ponteiro para o primeiro elemento, logo quando faz o `sizeof` apanha o tamanho do ponteiro e não o tamanho do vetor.

Algo simples que demonstra isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tamVet(int *vet){
  printf("\n%d", sizeof(vet)); // 8
}

int main(void){
  int vetor[10];
  printf("\n%d", sizeof(vetor)); // 40
  tamVet(vetor);
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qVwMBO)

Tenha em atenção que os valores que vê na saida podem variar dependendo da arquitetura, mas é garantido que o `printf` do `vetor` no `main` lhe dá o tamanho do vetor todo em bytes, que irá corresponder a `sizeof(int) * 10`. E é também garantido que na função vai ver o tamanho de um ponteiro para `int`, ou seja de um `int*`.

Sempre que precisar do tamanho de um vetor numa função a solução é passar o tamanho para essa função. Esse tamanho é possível de calcular no escopo onde o vetor foi construído precisamente com o calculo que você fez:

```
sizeof(vet) / sizeof(vet[0]);
```

**Mas apenas no escopo onde o vetor foi criado**.

Se olhar para a função `qsort` por exemplo, que permite ordenar um vetor, vai reparar que o segundo parâmetro é na verdade o tamanho do vetor.

Comment: Mas, digamos que  a própria função deseje saber o tamanho do vetor, como posso fazer ?

Comment: @Fernando Foi como eu respondi. Não tem como saber, dentro da função só tem um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento na memoria, logo não tem como. Se a função deseja saber o tamanho, tem que o receber como parametro.